# Spring MVC 4 Project Template in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am looking at using IntelliJ as my primary IDE for spring for a number of reasons but I confused about the project templates in IntelliJ. If i create a new project I can choose Spring 4 but then later in the project creation wizard/dialog it only lists MVC 3 project template.

If I do not choose a template I will get the Spring 4 libs downloaded and web project created but there is no pom, controller, or jsp created.

If I choose the MVC 3 template during the project creation I get a sample controller, configured WEB-INF, views directory, etc...however I get all the Spring 3 libs downloaded because of the pom that get created by the template.

Obviously I can go in create the needed items if I don't choose the template or I can update the pom to use the spring 4 libs but it seems like there should be MVC 4 template that I can add.

Is there a place to download new templates from JetBrains or documentation on how to create/edit templates that I am just overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a project manually yourself, then save it as a template for future use:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/saving-project-as-template.html

Answer (score 0):

Goto Settings>Plugins then search for spring mvc and enable it